# How to map random cardesian points in a 2d array

Tags: graph-theory, application-of-theory, applicative

I was wondering if there is any algorithm, theoretical or already implemented, or if its even possible at all, where, given `N` random `points (x,y)` we can relatively map them in a 2d array where each mapped point in the 2d-array has the property that its neighboring points (at most 8 points around it) are the closest to that point.

I would also like to add an extra restriction that no node in the 2d array is `NULL` meaning that if we have for example `N = 1 Million` elements then the 2d array would be `sqrt(N) x sqrt(N)` or `1000 x 1000` dimension, where each element of that array occupies a point.

In addition, we can also consider sorting, if it can help, as of x-coordinate and as of y-coordinate...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems impossible

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible in general.

The reason is that the grid-distance is symmetric while being closest neighbors is not a symmetric relation.

If you have many points ($\geq 9$) close to the origin and then a point at, say, $(M,0)$ for some large $M$.

The point at $(M,0)$ has a its closest neighbors as some of the points which are closest to the origin, but these points consider it as the farthest point from them.